# React Can't Access Array Inside Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to access an array within an object. The object form is:

```
{memes : { 
    data: {memes: Array(100)}
    success: true 
}}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import API from './functions/api';
import styles from './App.module.css';

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    memes: []
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    API.get().then(
      res => {
        // axios function returns Object
        const memes = res.data

        this.setState({ memes })
      }
    )
  }

  displayMemes(){

    console.log( this.state.memes );
    
    // memes: {
    //   data: {
    //     memes: Array(100)
    //   }
    // }

    this.state.memes.data.memes.forEach( meme => { 
      // Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')...
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className={ styles.container }>
        { this.displayMemes() }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Clearly I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I'm fairly new to this, the solution has to be simple.

I'm trying to get data from an open API ('https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes') to practise implementing different types of React apps.

Comment: Potentially multiple issues: You initialize `this.state.memes` to be an empty array (`memes: []`) and arrays don't have a `data` property (`this.state.memes.data.memes.forEach(...)`). Initialize the data to match what your code expects. Also if `console.log(this.state.memes)` displays `{memes: ...}` then that means `this.state.memes` actually has a property `memes`, so you would need to access `this.state.memes.memes....`. You should take a step back, think about how you want the data to look like that your component operators on and then make sure that you set that data correctly.

Comment: Try to `console.log(this.state.memes)` and see what you are getting.

Comment: Please check your `res.data` on API get. If `res.data` has only: `memes: [.....]`, then you may use de-structuring and try replacing: `const memes = res.data` with `const {memes} = res.data;`. Also, please see if you are able to use `?.` -> Optional chaining. So, instead of `this.state.memes...` you may try `this.state?.memes?.data?.....`.

Comment: @FelixKling after retrieving the data from the API it comes in the form: Object.memes.data.data.memes, it's not great I know. The code I posted above is quickly trying to get things to work, and how I overlooked the need to check that the data exists before I set anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling an API is an asynchronous action which takes some time to resolve.
You can initialize `memes` with a null value first.

```
state = {
  memes: null
}
```

Check if `memes` is not null before calling `displayMemes` so that you prevent calling it before getting the API response.

```
  render(){
    return(
      <div className={styles.container}>
        {this.state.memes && this.displayMemes()}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        const memes = res.data.memes

        this.setState({ memes })
```

Answer (score 0):

The forEach function always returns undefined after traversing through the array. Change it to map which returns an array.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    memes: null,
    isLoading: true
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((memes) => {
        this.setState({ memes });
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      });
  }

  displayMemes() {
    return this.state.memes.data.memes.map((meme) => {
      return <div>{meme.name}</div>;
    })
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.isLoading ? "No memes" : <div>{this.displayMemes()}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I added isLoading to call displayMemes when data has been fetched.